# 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and no accessible extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I was wondering if someone can advise me on how to fix this Compiler error please? I'm trying to get the input from the drop down Calendar and turn that into a string. Thanks in advance :)

```
protected void Calendar1_Selection(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Calender1.SelectedDate.HasValue) {
            dateOfBirth.Text = Calender1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Calander1.Visible = false;

        }
```

Comment: What is the data type of `Calender1`?

Comment: It is <asp:Calendar></asp:Calendar>. Sorry I'm new to C# and ASP.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because SelectedDate is of the type `DateTime` not `Nullable<DateTime>`

According to the documentation

> The default value is MinValue.

This means you should structure your if statement like

```
if (Calender1.SelectedDate != DateTime.MinValue)
```

For further details please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate?view=netframework-4.8